# Error during a loop to extract content from an scraped link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping

I've been working on this web scraper for a while and trying to get the body content of different links of an online newsletter. Therefore, if I breakdown the code for the second loop and run it separately, it will return the correct results, however, if the same part is put inside a loop in the bigger script, it will return the error **"IndexError: list index out of range".**

This is the script that 2nd loop returns the error (**UPDATED**):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

def pages(myurl):
  # opening up connection, grabbing the page
  uClient = uReq(myurl)
  page_html = uClient.read()
  uClient.close()

  # html parsing
  page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


  dt = []
  ttl = []
  name = []
  body = []
  source = []

  # grabs each newsletter subjects
  titular = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"})
  titular[0]

  tit1 = titular[0]
  fixed = 'https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all'

  for tit1 in titular:

    date = tit1.span.text
    dt.append(date)

    title = tit1.h2.a.text
    ttl.append(title)

    link = tit1.h2.a["href"].strip()
    source.append(fixed + link)

  df = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns =['date'])
  df['title'] = ttl
  df['link'] = source

  for link in df['link']:
    
    new_link = fixed + link
    page = uReq(new_link)
    page_html_1 = page.read()
    page.close()
    
    page_soup = soup(page_html_1, "html.parser")

    content = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"entry cuerpo-noticias CUERPO"})
    content[0].text
    cont1 = content[0].text
    body.append(cont1)

  df['content'] = body

  print(df)

  #df.to_csv(u'C:/Users/snpw9/Desktop/Scripts/sample_scrap.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
   
pages('https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all/taxport_3_230__1.html') #Banca y Fintech
pages('https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all/taxport_3_20__1.html') #Bolsa y Monedas
pages('https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all/taxport_3_226__1.html') #Pensiones
pages('https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all/taxport_3_228__1.html') #Seguros
```

It would be very helpful to make this part work, hopefully, with your help!

The second script without the loop (which work properly):

```
  from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

  myurl = 'https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all/noticias/mercados/banca-fintech/bancoestado- 
  destina-90-millones-para-los-gastos-de-internet-de-sus/2020-07-07/152240.html'

  #def pages(myurl):
  # opening up connection, grabbing the page
  uClient = uReq(myurl)
  page_html = uClient.read()
  uClient.close()

  #html parsing
  page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

  #grabs each newsletter subjects
  content = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"entry cuerpo-noticias CUERPO"})
  cont1 = content[0].text
  print(cont1)
```

Comment: the error should be pointing to a line number - please add that in your question. And you are using `contents[0].text` , should it be `content[0].text` instead ??

Comment: Did you print `new_link` inside your `loop` n see if it's taking the right value ?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Hi, thank you for your comments! the part contents[0].text , should it be content[0].text instead ?? is not a problem in the script, it was just a typo error in here only (in the script is written correct whether is contents or content).

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat for the part new_link inside the loop, it was printing the fixed part twice, I don't truly know why, but after deleting that part and using "link" object only, stills returns the error: list index out of range. The error occur when I call content[0].text, like specifying the index and get the text only. When I run it on a separate script, the results shows the body content as it should be

Comment: so it means you are not passing the right URL . probably your `df['link']` is not the data you want to loop through. does `df['link']` have elements like this => `'/noticias/mercados/banca-fintech/bancoestado- 
  destina-90-millones-para-los-gastos-de-internet-de-sus/2020-07-07/152240.html'` ?

Comment: 'df['link']' is used to append both part of the website as the 'fixed' part which would be ''https://www.df.cl/noticias/site/tax/port/all'' and the 'link' part which would be '''/noticias/mercados/banca-fintech/bancoestado-destina-90-millones-para-los-gastos-de-internet-de-sus/2020-07-07/152240.html"'. Will update the post with the entire script so you can visualize better

Comment: your class selector is not there in second element that comes as link - that is this one - `noticias/mercados/banca-fintech/la-norma-que-gatillo-la-perdida-contable-de-casi-us-1-000-millones-de/2020-07-12/181959.html` . but it exists in the previous URL.

Comment: If I complete the URL in the second element with the the initial part which is called 'Fixed', shouldn't allow the script to go through and pick the class correctly?

Comment: no bro , if you want you can pass the second link to your code-block which doesn't have loop , n check - it doesnt have these 2 classes - `cuerpo-noticias CUERPO`

Comment: i'd suggest just use class `entry`  , remove `cuerpo-noticias CUERPO`  from your code n try